# How to open facebook, twitter page using PHP Curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, instagram, php-curl

When I try to open **url1(https://www.google.co.in)**, **url2(https://www.amazon.com)**, **url5(https://www.instagram.com)** its working fine that is I can load url1, url2 and url5 but when I try to open *url3(https://www.facebook.com)*, *url4(https://www.twitter.com)*, its printing my error message:"**Error, Unable to open.**" as it can't open facebook, twitter page. I dont want to use API. Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php

    $curl = curl_init();

    //url1 = https://www.google.co.in
    //url2 = https://www.amazon.com
    //url3 = https://www.facebook.com
    //url4 = https://www.twitter.com
    //url5 = https://www.instagram.com

    $url ="https://www.facebook.com";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    if($output)
    {
        echo $output;       
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error, Unable to open.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `echo curl_error($curl)` if you are curious about the error.

Comment: Also, please have a look to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly, why not use the API? you are probably trying to do something you are not supposed to do, that´s why it does not work.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So they do things to make it harder.

Comment: @luschn actually, it doesn't work because he's not following [HTTP redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), and he's not supplying any [User-Agent string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

Answer (score 1):

when debugging issues like that, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE. furthermore, when debugging, don't use echo, use var_dump. if you did that, you'd see something like

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.facebook.com/
*   Trying 157.240.20.35...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a03:2880:f10a:83:face:b00c:0:25de: Network is unreachable
* Connected to www.facebook.com (157.240.20.35) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.facebook.com
*  start date: Dec 15 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 22 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.facebook.com" matched cert's "*.facebook.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
< Location: https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-FB-Debug: x3NeeaaJHxPQkX5Z9H7yMX3evzYJocXmZpzMV6GoWtacO8bXLL3O58vidPHZUvXTuP9iE9pHPEnbr/RvNsT23Q==
< Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:12:51 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.facebook.com left intact
string(0) ""
```

the problem being that facebook tried to issue a HTTP redirect (to `https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser`), and you didn't follow it. enable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to have curl automatically handle redirects. why did facebook redirect you? because you didn't supply any user-agent header. set one that facebook will recognize as supported with CURLOPT_USERAGENT, for example `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0` (aka Firefox 52 ESR running on Windows 7 x64)

as for twitter.com,

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.twitter.com/
*   Trying 104.244.42.193...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.twitter.com (104.244.42.193) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=4337446; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Twitter, Inc.; OU=tsa_o Point of Presence; CN=twitter.com
*  start date: Jul 25 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 30 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.twitter.com" matched cert's "www.twitter.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.twitter.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< content-length: 0
< date: Mon, 19 Feb 2018 09:17:51 GMT
< location: https://twitter.com/
< server: tsa_o
< set-cookie: personalization_id="v1_ersTgWQIOjuJkjk6VFUlXw=="; Expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 09:17:51 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A151903187127250514; Expires=Wed, 19 Feb 2020 09:17:51 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< x-connection-hash: aae827a6347e88db5f417a0c31bba366
< x-response-time: 101
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.twitter.com left intact
string(0) ""
```

- it tried to redirect you to the non-www url version of the site, and again, you didn't follow the redirect. enable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to have curl automatically follow http redirects.